# Shell script recursion behaves unexpectedly

Tags: bash, shell, recursion

I have a shell script to count all my files and directories sizes using recursive function
Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
count() {
  local file
  total=$2
  files=(`ls $1`)
  for file in "$files"
  do
    if [ -d "$1/$file" ]
    then
      count "$1/$file" $total
    else
      #size=`du $file | grep -o [0-9]*`
      #total=$(($2 + $size))
      echo "$1/$file"
    fi
  done
}
total=0
count . $total
echo "$total"
```

I have error somewhere it just goes into the first directory prints the file and stops. Where's my error? :)

Comment: Why not just use the standard `find` utility?

Comment: Or bash 4 `globstar`.

Comment: It's task I have to write for university class

Comment: Can you clarify your goal here?  Do you want to know how many files you have or do you want to know how much disk space is being used?

Comment: Please use shell globbing instead of [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: disk size i guess i have other errors other than the array notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
for file in "$files"
```

It should be:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"
```

`$files` just expands to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Note: The recursive shell-function approach is suboptimal in real life (given that there are specific utilities such as `du` that do the job), but needed to satisfy the OP's specific requirements.

A revised version of your code that demonstrates several advanced `bash` techniques; note that the function has been renamed to `sumFileSizes` to better reflect its purpose:

- Declares **local variables**, including one with `-i` to type it as an integer
- Uses a string composed of quoted and unquoted elements (wildcards) for **safe globbing** (pathname expansion) - `"$1/"*`
- Uses **`stdout` output to "return" the desired result** and captures it with **command substitution** (`$(...)`) rather than trying to pass a variable "by reference" (which `bash` doesn't directly support).
- Uses a **process substitution** via stdin (`< <(...)`) to provide a command's output as input to another command.
- Shows **relevant shell options** (set with `shopt`) that govern **globbing** (pathname expansion) behavior.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

  # Recursive function to report the *combined size of all files* 
  # in the specified directory's *subtree*.
sumFileSizes() {
    # Declare the variable as an integer (-i) to ensure
    # that += assignments performs *arithmetic*.
  local -i size=0
  local file
    # Loop over all files/subdirectories      
  for file in "$1/"*; do
    if [[ -d $file ]]; then # item is a *directory*
      # Recurse, adding to the size so far.
      size+=$($FUNCNAME "$file")
    else # a *file*
      # Add this file's size to the size so far.
      # Note: `du` reports `{size} {file}`, so we need to 
      # extract the 1st token, which we do with `read` and
      # process substitution, followed by printing the 1st token 
      # and capturing the output via command substitution.
      size+=$(read thisSize unused < <(du -- "$file"); printf $thisSize)
    fi
  done
    # Output combined size.
  printf $size
}

  # Ensure that:
  # - globs expand to *nothing* in case there are *no* matching files/directories:
  #   option `nullglob`
  # - hidden files/directories (those whose names start with '.') are included:
  #   option `dotglob`
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

  # Make `du` report sizes in KB (this is the default on Linux).
export BLOCKSIZE=1024

  # Invoke the recursive function and capture
  # its outoput.
totalSize=$(sumFileSizes .)

  # Output combined size of all files
  # in multiples of 1KB.
echo "$totalSize"
```

Comment: `file` should be declared local too (though not very important in your case). `+1` anyway, good to see well written Bash code. Oh a detail: in the `else` branch you're not sure it's file... it could be something else (fifo, link, etc.)—oh but yeah, [everything is a file in UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thanks for the pointer re `file` - fixed. Good point re subtleties of what's a file or not, but the file-test operators `-d` and `-f` at least get the basic dichotomy right: `-d` reports true for a directory _or symlink to_ a directory; `-f` reports true for a `file` _or symlink to_ a file. By contrast, `du` and `find` by default treat symlinks as _themselves_ rather than _what they point to_; `-L` (and to a lesser extent `-H`) fixes that. Also, I've revised the answer heavily after realizing it's the combined *size*, not the _file count_ that's desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the size of a directory recursively, try this:

```
du -sh
```

-h is for human readable and -s is for summarize

Comment: yeah but I want to do that manually not use the implemented function it's for a task